# How to call linked list without array implementation?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, stack, call

For this assignment, I write a program, which will calculate the results of Reverse Polish expressions that are provided by the user.

I must use a linked list to maintain the stack for this program (array implementations of the stack will not receive full credit).

I must handle the following situations (errors):
    Too many operators (+ - / *)
    Too many operands (doubles)
    Division by zero

The program will take in a Polish expression that separates the operators and operands by a single space, and terminates the expression with an equals sign.
The program will continue to take and evaluate expressions until the user enters a zero (0) on a line by itself followed by a new line.
my sample output should show the handling of all the error conditions as well as make use of all of the operators. But when I execute the program it says 
Error: Main method not found in class program1.Program1, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
Java Result: 1
I have no idea how to call linked list without array implementations. Also 
RefObject class and TryparseHelper are below in the same package. tnx

```
 package program1;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.lang.IllegalStateException;


  public class Program1 {


 public class Node<T>
 {
public T Data;
public Node<T> Next;
 }

  public class Stack<T>
  {
    private Node<T> top = null;

public final void Push(T value)
{
    top = new Node<T>();
    top.Data = value;
    top.Next = top;
}

public final T Pop()
{
    if (top == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot pop if the stack is empty.");
    }

    T topValue = top.Data;
    top = top.Next;

    return topValue;
}

public final boolean IsEmpty()
{
    return top == null;
}

public final void Clear()
{
    top = null;
}
   }

     public class ReversePolishCalculator
     {


public final void Calculator()
{
    String expression = "";
    while (!expression.equals("0"))
    {
        System.out.print("Enter expression: ");
        expression = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        try
        {
            System.out.println(" = " + Calculate(expression));
        }
        catch (RuntimeException ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<Double>();

private double Calculate(String expression)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    stack.Clear();

    String[] tokens = expression.split("[ ]", -1);

    for (String token : tokens)
    {
        double value = 0;
        RefObject<Double> tempRef_value = new RefObject<Double>(value);
        if (TryParseHelper.tryParseDouble(token, tempRef_value))
        {
        value = tempRef_value.argValue;
            stack.Push(value);
        }
        else
        {
        value = tempRef_value.argValue;
            DoOperation(token);
        }
    }

    if (!stack.IsEmpty())
    {
        result = stack.Pop();
    }

    if (!stack.IsEmpty())
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Too many operands.");
    }

    return result;
}

private void DoOperation(String token)
{
    if (stack.IsEmpty())
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Too many operators.");
    }

    double rhs = stack.Pop();

    if (stack.IsEmpty())
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Too many operators.");
    }

    double lhs = stack.Pop();

    switch (token)
    {
        case "+":
            stack.Push(lhs + rhs);
            break;
        case "-":
            stack.Push(lhs - rhs);
            break;
        case "*":
            stack.Push(lhs * rhs);
            break;
        case "/":
            if (rhs == 0.0)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Divide by zero.");
            }

            stack.Push(lhs / rhs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected operator: " + token);
    }
}
  }


  }
```

package program1; TryParseHelper

```
  /**
  *
 * @author David
   */
 public final class TryParseHelper
   {
public static boolean tryParseInt(String s, RefObject<Integer> result)
{
    try
    {
        result.argValue = Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean tryParseShort(String s, RefObject<Short> result)
{
    try
    {
        result.argValue = Short.parseShort(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean tryParseLong(String s, RefObject<Long> result)
{
    try
    {
        result.argValue = Long.parseLong(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean tryParseByte(String s, RefObject<Byte> result)
{
    try
    {
        result.argValue = Byte.parseByte(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean tryParseDouble(String s, RefObject<Double> result)
{
    try
    {
        result.argValue = Double.parseDouble(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean tryParseFloat(String s, RefObject<Float> result)
{
    try
    {
        result.argValue = Float.parseFloat(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean tryParseBoolean(String s, RefObject<Boolean> result)
{
    try
    {
        result.argValue = Boolean.parseBoolean(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
   }
```

package program1; RefObj

/**
    *
    * @author David
     */

```
 public final class RefObject<T>
 {
public T argValue;
public RefObject(T refArg)
{
    argValue = refArg;
}
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?  All you need to do is to simulate a stack using a linked list.

Comment: Question is simple. How to call non static method without array

Answer (score 0):

As the error message you've pasted says: To run your program, add to `Program1` class a method with this signature `public static void main(String[] args)`. Write in it the code you want to run, e.g., `System.out.println("hi");` or whatever.

**Update:** As I understood from your comment, it seems like your problem is trying to call a non-static method `Calculator()` from `main(...)`. First, you need a background on class vs object and static vs non-static.

A class is a template or a blueprint. An object is an instantiation of that blueprint. For example, a description of a car is a class, any car is an object. Another example is your `Stack` class and the `Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<Double>()` object you've used to calculate an expression.

When you call `pop()` it needs a specific stack to run on. A specific object. For example, you could have 2 stacks at the same time, and calling `pop()` on one of them shouldn't affect the other. That's why the method `pop()` is non-static.

Now, let's think of the `Program1` class: Are you really thinking of creating multiple program1 and running them/calling their methods in your code? And would each program1 have a different state from the other? Each stack could have different contents at any time, but program1 doesn't really have any content or *state*.

When you have a method that doesn't depend on any specific object or a particular state, you mark it as static. For example, a method that adds 2 numbers should be static. Same goes for your `Calculator()` method.

So, back to your question, to call non-static method `Calculator()` from `main(...)`, you'll either have to:

(1) convert `Calculator()` into a static method. You need to ask yourself "Is this method related only to a specific instance, a specific object?". For example, the `pop()` method of `Stack` is very related to a certain stack object. If you call it on 2 stack objects, it'll give different results. That's why it should be a non-static method, i.e., a method that depends on a particular instance.
However, `Calculator()` seems like a method that doesn't really depend on anything else. The fact that it uses a member variable called `stack` is accidental. You can move the `stack` variable inside `Calculator()`. Or you could just make `stack` static as well.

(2) You could, although it wouldn't make much sense, create an instance of `Program1` then call `Calculator()` on it.

I know the difference between class and object, and static and non-static, can be confusing in the beginning. Read more on it, you'll get comfortable with it with time.

**For the without-arrays question:** If I understand correctly, you have a problem with the array in `main(String[] args)`. The array here is a must for the program to run and is not related to the stack's implementation. So, I don't expect you teacher to mind having it.

Finally, note that the code, I think, has some problems so don't expect it to run from the first time. And that's absolutely normal, and you'll need to know how to trace a code. Good luck!

Comment: Right now I'm learning Java and I'm a beginner. I wrote the codes using my teacher's help but I don't have access to him right now. Also you mentioned a good point but I think it's better to read the codes first! Calculate method is not static and I think I can't call non static method on the main method. In addition to this, I said I'm trying to use them through linked list not array implementations. Tnx for help

Comment: @David.Kaufmann you didn't mention before that your problem is calling non-static methods from static ones. Totally updated the answer. For the array part, not sure I get you, but added an answer depending on my understanding. Sorry for doubting you, but linked list isn't so simple and it's hard to believe someone (as from your initial question) who couldn't read a compilation error could write it. You're welcome.